# Add if statement script to new rows of spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm struggling to append an if-statement down a column because my data table adds rows each day. I need the if-statement to be added to the new rows that join the spreadsheet every 24 hours.

Within the table, column C contains a date that my if-statement is referencing.

I'm trying to add the if-statement in a column off to the right (in column Q) that will tell me if the date in column C is before or after today's date. The problem is I'm not sure how to add the function for the incremental rows that are appended to the table each day. Below is what I have:

```
function AddFormula() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var column = spreadsheet.getRange('Q:Q').activate();
  var lastrow = 
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=if($C2<(today()),1,0)');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
}
```

You may be able to tell I'm totally stuck because above has several errors. How can I have my if statement added to the active rows down column Q on a daily basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function AddFormula() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const srg=sh.getRange(1,17).setFormula('=if($C2<(today()),1,0)');
  const drg=sh.getRange(1,17,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  srg.autoFill(drg,SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper this script works but turns the text bold? It also overwrites the row header which isn't critical but is there a way to start the script on row 2?

Comment: Sure all that is possible but it wasn’t described in the question

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an array formula in your top row?

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C2:C < TODAY(),1,0))
```

To limit the range that the array formula is applied to you can use `indirect()`

```
=ArrayFormula(if(indirect("C2:C"&counta(C2:C)+1,1) < TODAY(),1,0))
```

Comment: Hi @James D this runs the output down my whole workbook whether or not there's any data in the row to the left. Maybe should have called this out above, but I'd like the bottom of the data table to be flush (instead of having row Q run down the whole column). Otherwise I would have just added the syntax to each cell down the column ahead of time.

Comment: @econobro see the edit and use of the indirect function to limit the range. Would this solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @James D quick question.. if I wanted to change the logic to flag dates prior to March 12th, how would I change the syntax? Trying to just edit your "< TODAY()" to "< (3/12/2020)" doesn't work.