# Updating array formula syntax to change reference date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using below array formula provided by user in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312185/add-if-statement-script-to-new-rows-of-spreadsheet/61312850?noredirect=1#comment108484469_61312850). It works great, but I want to adjust the syntax to change the flag for dates before or after 3/12/2020.

I've tried just changing the "today()" portion below to "3/12/2020" but it's not working for some reason. I either get all "1's" or "0's" depending on the direction of the sign.

How can I update below to change the reference date from today to March 12th?

```
 =ArrayFormula(if(indirect("C2:C"&counta(C2:C)+1,1) < TODAY(),1,0))
```

Comment: Replace `TODAY()` with `DATE(2020, 3, 12)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks @kishkin. That worked!

Answer (score 1):

> Replace `TODAY()` with `DATE(2020, 3, 12)` - [kishkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347224/updating-array-formula-syntax-to-change-reference-date/61352739#comment108529311_61347224)